# How does a Bourdon tube maintain constant volume?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, measurements, volume, instrument

I would like to understand why a Bourdon tube works, the working principle  is described on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_measurement#Bourdon_gauge) as:

> The Bourdon pressure gauge uses the principle that a flattened tube tends to straighten or regain its circular form in cross-section when pressurized. This change in cross-section may be hardly noticeable, involving moderate stresses within the elastic range of easily workable materials. The strain of the material of the tube is magnified by forming the tube into a C shape or even a helix, such that the entire tube tends to straighten out or uncoil elastically as it is pressurized.

I have searched far and wide for a detailed explanation and have not found one. Is it possible to show (without too too much hassle) that the volume change in the tube is negligible, and maybe an approximate formula for the amount of straightening the tube will experience for a given pressure?

Comment: There is a *slight* change of volume when the tube straightens. This is usually negligible compared to the pressurized volume, so we can safely say "constant volume"

Comment: Okay, do you know if there is a simple way to show that the change in radius of curvature is going to be that much larger than the change in volume, that we can normally neglect the change in volume?

Comment: You can't compare the change in the radius of curvature with the change in volume. They have different units:  meters versus meters-cubed. What *is* compared in the change in volume of the Bourdon tube with volume of the system whose pressure is being measured. These volumes  have the same units.

Comment: So how does this work? I was thinking more about temperature measurement, if one can show the volume change of the tube is negligible compared to the volume of the tube itself that should be enough right?